# How to suppress units such that they can be passed to viewport key?

Tags: graphics, dimensions

How to suppress units in length macros such that they can be passed to `viewport`. See the following Minimal Not Working Example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\IBox
\savebox\IBox{\includegraphics{bald}}
\newdimen\width
\newdimen\height
\width=\wd\IBox
\height=\ht\IBox
\parindent=0bp
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\includegraphics[viewport=0 0 \strip@pt\width \strip@pt\height]{bald}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\width` and `\height` are often used temporally by macros like `\raisebox` and then set to the content size. It's not an issue here, I just want to point that out. I'm planning to add this to `\includegraphics` in the next feature release of `adjustbox`.

Comment: @Martin: Can you give me an example where `\width` and `\height` will affect `\raisebox` in a practical situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `viewport` option actually accepts units, but defaults to `bp` if none are used. The issue here is that the macro is eating the space behind it which is used as a separator by `viewport` (and also `trim`). The solution is to wrap the expression in `{ }` (which is removed afterwards) to protect the space:

```
\includegraphics[viewport=0 0 {\width} \height]{bald}
```